# Heroku payment is declaining from October month

Tags: heroku

[image: Heroku payment message]

Heroku can't accept my payment from last month I had tried different cards but was still unable to pay. It shows "Item can't be created - Do not honor".

Note:
Region - India.
Card - ICICI & Axis credit cards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service question and should be directed to Heroku. [We can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).